# React Components child component render twice - any way to fix this?

Tags: reactjs

```
When i click on Update Key button then Child1 component render every time so how can i resolve it.  
Note : I have create three component one parent component and two child component when i click on 
       parent component button to update child component, so child1 component increase to display 
       multiple time. so please resolved this as soon as possible.
```

When i click on Update Key button then Child1 component render every time so how can i resolve it.
Note : I have create three component one parent component and two child component when i click on
parent component button to update child component, so child1 component increase to display
multiple time. so please resolved this as soon as possible.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Child1 extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("mounted");
  }
  render() {
    console.log("rendered");
    return <div>Child</div>;
  }
}

class Child2 extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("mounted2");
  }
  render() {
    console.log("rendered2");
    return <div>Child2</div>;
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0,
    counter2: 0
  };

onCounter = () => this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 , counter2: this.state.counter2 + 1 });

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Child1 key={this.state.counter} />
        <Child2 key={this.state.counter2} />
        <button onClick={this.onCounter}>Update Key</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1):

my first response, I think I understand the question, I rewrote it using react hooks as it makes it easier to read and requires no configuration changes just make sure your running the latest version of react.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function Child1(props) {
  return <h1>Child{props.input}</h1>;
}
function Child2(props) {
  return <h1>Child{props.input}</h1>;
}

function App() {
  let [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  let [counter2, setCounter2] = useState(1);

  let onCounter = () => {
    setCounter(counter+1)
    setCounter2(counter2+1)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Child1 input={counter} />
      <Child2 input={counter2} />
      <button onClick={onCounter}>Update Key</button>
    </>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because your Child component, i.e., `Child1` and `Child2` are using the same value as `key`. Both `counter` and `counter2` states have the same value and it is creating ambiguity in the ReactDOM. Here, you are not iterating over an `array` so there's is no need of using the `key` property. It will work fine. If you've to use the `key` property, make sure they are unique at the same level.

~Prayag